# Set Default To "Square (1:1)" Image Capture & Save With React Native App?

Tags: ios, react-native, crop, image-capture, react-native-camera

I'm in the process of developing an iOS/Android React Native App that will allow me to take photos of incoming packages.  However, currently photos are saved in 4:3 aspect ratio but I need the default to be a 1:1 "square" aspect ratio.

Is there a way to set the default image capture/save to be 1:1 "square"?

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer? thanks